# Wordpress Category Page 2 is 404

Tags: php, wordpress

My category pages work just fine. However, when viewing older pages (2, 3, 4, etc.), I receive a 404 error. In other words, "http://domain.com/stories/news" works fine, but "http://houstoncinemaartsfestival.org/stories/news/page/2" receives 404.

My permalinks were flushed. Here are my permalink settings:

**Custom Structure:** /stories/%category%/%postname%

**Category Base:** stories/.

(I am using "stories" as the blog post root folder. Then, the category name.)

Comment: What do you have the number of posts set to under `Admin > Settings > Reading`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you are not including the `paged` parameter to the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). You can use the [`global $query_string`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Preserving_Existing_Query_Parameters) if you need to modify the query to add `paged`.

```
global $query_string;
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( $query_string . "&paged=$paged" );
```